# invalid signature - JWT is required to have three segments

Tags: c#, owin-security

I am using `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` from Microsoft Owin Security and here is I am using code,

```
 var oAuthAuthorizationServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/token"), 
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider()
        };
```

CustomOAuthProvider,

```
  public class CustomOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        var lstClients = ClientService.GetClients();

        if (lstClients.Count <= 0) return base.ValidateClientAuthentication(context);

        context.TryGetFormCredentials(out var clientId, out var clientSecret);

        if (lstClients.Count(c => c.ClientId == clientId) > 0
            && lstClients.Count(c => c.ClientPassword == clientSecret) > 0)
        {
            context.Validated(clientId);
        }

        return base.ValidateClientAuthentication(context);
    }

    public override Task GrantClientCredentials(OAuthGrantClientCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.ClientId));
        var props = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "client_id", context.ClientId },
            { "scope", string.Join(" ",context.Scope) }
        });
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(claimsIdentity, props);
        context.Validated(ticket);
        return base.GrantClientCredentials(context);
    }
}
```

I am here trying to add `scope`, but looks like this is not correct way to add, even all looks good and working and when I am trying to view token,

- in `jwt.IO` I am seeing invalid signature error.
- in `calebb.net`, it's saying  -  JWT is required to have three segments

What's wrong here? Please suggest.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For a JWT token to be valid, you have to have three segments as your error message says.

According to the documentation:

> In its compact form, JSON Web Tokens consist of three parts separated
>   by dots (.), which are:
>
> - Header
> - Payload
> - Signature
>
> Therefore, a JWT typically looks like the
>   following.
>
> `xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz`

You have to examine the code of your custom provider to ensure that those three segments are actually present. They have to be separated by a dot.

Comment: Thanks Tony, I have provide code for my custom provider, could you please suggest what wrong here?